# Somar dados de uma coluna

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> id .. produto...valor...id_venda...valortotal
>
> 01 .. Caneta.... 2,00....1..........30,00
>
> 02 .. Borracha. 4,00....2...........25,50
>
> 03 .. .Lapis...... 5,00....1...........10,00
>
> 04 .. Apontador 9,00...1...........200,00

Bom considerando essa tabela , eu precisaria somar todos os valeres da coluna `valortotal` mas so os que tem o `id_venda` igual a 1 como eu faria isso ?

ex :  ID_VENDA 1 VALOR TOTAL 240,00 .

Comment: esses dados estão vindo de algum banco de dados? Qual?

Comment: Estão sim , do MySQL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use o comando [SUM()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) que soma os valores de uma coluna:

```
SELECT
  SUM(`valortotal`) as 'Valor Total'
FROM
  produtos
WHERE
  id_venda = 1;
```

**Veja funcionando aqui**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb5d8/2

Comment: Obrigado, me quebro um galho ;)